# Ensuring Exclusion of Weak Ciphers in TLS Handshake using WireShark and PktMon

Tags: ssl, encryption, tls1.2, wireshark

I am currently working on enhancing the security of our application communication, specifically focusing on the TLS handshake process. I want to make sure that weak ciphers are not part of the TLS handshake, and I am trying to achieve this using WireShark and the PktMon tool on Windows. I have removed the TLS 1.0 and 1.1 and disabled weak ciphers in TLS 1.2. (In Windows)

I have configured my server (Cloud) to use only strong ciphers, but I would like to **validate** this by inspecting the TLS handshake packets with WireShark and PktMon. However, I am unsure about the specific steps and filters I need to apply to effectively identify and confirm the exclusion of weak ciphers during the TLS handshake.

Need to know how to use WireShark and PktMon to inspect TLS handshake packets and ensure that weak ciphers are not being utilized?  Additionally, if there are specific filters or settings within WireShark or PktMon that I should be aware of to highlight or filter out weak ciphers, that information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"weak ciphers are not part of the TLS handshake,"* - do you mean that they are not offered by the client (but not actually used) or that they are not used as the shared cipher? The first can be seen in the first packet in the handshake - the ClientHello. The second can be seen in the ServerHello from the server. All of this is kind of obvious accessible from within Wireshark.

Comment: Yes agree. but I am new to WireShark and other tools, so need clear steps to find these cipher's in transaction

Comment: Instead of expecting others to take you by the hand  I recommend that you do a bit more research yourself by using a search engine and learn the basics yourself. Searching for [wireshark show ciphers](https://www.google.com/search?q=wireshark+show+ciphers) provides hits like [this](https://www.freekb.net/Article?id=1408) which includes both ClientHello and ServerHello with images on how these are shown in Wireshark. You will also find videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkLX5m0snRU) for explanation.

Comment: Thank you for providing the information and links. It's valuable for deeper exploration, and I believe the question is entirely valid and deserves a place on Stack Overflow. Instead of being marked for closure, the question contributes to the community by bringing attention to resources like the one you shared which can benefit many users who might not have come across those links just by doing basic research.

Comment: This is surely true if one considers SO as the main point of getting knowledge. I myself think though is that SO is just one of many valuable resources and that users should not rely solely on SO to link to other resources. Instead they should be able to find these by their own and only use SO for the kind of problems which are not already well covered somewhere else. That's what search engines are for.

Comment: Agreed,  Appreciated your time. I will make sure to do enough research here afer.